# What is the JSF2.0 equivalent of the HTML anchor tag

Tags: jsf-2, anchor

When I use the `h:link` tag as follows, the JSF system reports as *This link is disabled because a navigation case could not be matched.*

```
<h:link rendered="#{empty applicationScope.rendered ? false : true}" disabled="#{applicationScope.disabled eq 'true' ? true : false}" outcome="http://www.myblogname.blogspot.com/" >
 <h:graphicImage url="#{applicationScope.url}"    alt="#{applicationScope.alt}" title="#{applicationScope.title}" styleClass="rGap ui-corner-all" />  
</h:link>
```

It seems it is searching for an internal navigation case, but how can I specify an external hyperlink?

**Summery of the question:**
What is the JSF equivalent of the following HTML?

```
<a href="http://www.amazon.com" > Amazon </a>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using the [`h:outputLink`](http://www.jsftoolbox.com/documentation/help/12-TagReference/html/h_outputLink.html) tag. Use value attribute to specify the rendered `href`.

```
<h:outputLink id="amazonLink" value="http://www.amazon.com">
  Amazon
</h:outputLink>
```

It should be possible to adapt your sample code like this:

```
<h:outputLink 
  rendered="#{empty applicationScope.rendered ? false : true}" 
  disabled="#{applicationScope.disabled eq 'true' ? true : false}" 
  value="http://www.myblogname.blogspot.com/">
    <h:graphicImage 
      url="#{applicationScope.url}" 
      alt="#{applicationScope.alt}" 
      title="#{applicationScope.title}" 
      styleClass="rGap ui-corner-all" />  
</h:outputLink>
```

<strike>**Note**: I don't think the `h:outputLink` tag has a `disabled` attribute, so setting it to true or false (like in your code sample above) may not have an effect. You'll have to try it and see.</strike>

As @Matteo brought out in a comment, the `disabled` attribute should work with the `h:outputLink` tag.

Comment: The disable attribute is supported: If the "disabled" attribute is specified, do not render the HTML "a" anchor element or the "href" element. Instead, render a "span" element.

Comment: @Matteo Thanks for the clarification. That's really useful information. I'll update my answer accordingly.